# Limit of integrals where both bounds and integrand depend on $n$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

I want to find the limit 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{[0,n]}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{-2x} \, d\lambda(x)$$
I have noted the following: It is well known that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converges to $\exp(x)$ in the limit. So I'm certain the limit is equal to the improper integral 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx=1$$
My question is: How can I argue/use the convergence of the integrated when I can't pull the limit into the integral, as the bound depends on it?

Also: I'm not taking the measure $\lambda$ into account at all, am I making a mistake there?

Comment: Did you try DCT, finding a limit on $f_n(x)$?

Comment: @Alex How would a discrete cosine transform help here? I've only ever used it in image processing, never in this context...

Comment: DCT=Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: This statement is certainly incorrect: 'converges to $\exp(x)$ for large $n$. It converges in the limit, i.e. for $n \to \infty$

Comment: @Alex pardon the sloppiness. Edited :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
1_{[0,n]} (x) \left( 1 + \frac x n \right)^n e^{-2x} \le e^{-x} \text{ for } 0 \le x < +\infty \\
\text{and } e^{-x} \text{ does not depend on $n$} \\
\text{and } \int_0^\infty \left| e^{-x} \right| \, dx < +\infty
$$
Therefore the dominated convergence theorem is applicable.

Comment: Interesting: https://wikidiff.com/applicable/appliable

Comment: @Alex : You should also notice the relationship between "apply" and "application." $\qquad$

Comment: @So in this case 'dominating' function $g(x)$ s.t. $g(x) \geq f_n(x) \forall x$ and $f(x)$, to which $f_n$ converges coincide?

Comment: @Alex : Yes. $\qquad$